Induced representation for an ergodic $C^*$-dynamical system
Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra with identity $I$, $G$ be a compact group, and $\alpha: G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ be a strongly continuous action of $G$ on $A$. Consider the $C^*$-dynamical system $(A, G, \alpha)$, which is ergodic, i.e.,
$$\left\{a\in A : \alpha_g(a) = a\,\forall g\in G\right\} = \mathbb{C}I.$$
Let $H = {g \in G : \alpha_g(a) = a , \forall a \in A}$ denote the stabilizer subgroup of $G$.
Question: Given a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{K}$ and a unitary representation $U: H \to \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{K})$, does there exist a well-defined notion of an induced representation of $G$ that is induced from $U$?
My first doubt was that what would be the non-commutative analogue of the representing Hilbert space $L^2(G/H, \rho, \mathcal{K})$, where $\rho$ is the quasi-invariant measure on $G/H$, as seen in the classical case $A = C(G/H)$.
If this notion is known (or unknown), I would greatly appreciate any helpful comment, suggestion, or reference to relevant research. Thank you in advance!

How does $\alpha\colon G\to\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ relate to your question?
